# In C# how to get different IEqualityComparer<T> instance if generic type implements an interface

Tags: c#, generics, template-specialization

I have a generic method with unconstrained generic type. I need to get a different IEqualityComparer if type T implements an interface.

A code looks roughly like this:

```
public SomeState MergeCollection<T>(
    ICollection<T> thisValue, 
    ICollection<T> otherValue, 
    SomeStrategy strategy = SomeStrategy.Default, 
    IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    comparer = comparer ?? GetComparer<T>(strategy);
    // code using comparer
}

public IEqualityComparer<T> GetComparer<T>(SomeStrategy strategy)
{
    if(typeof(IMerge).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        return GetMergeComparer<T>(strategy);
    }
    else
    {
        return EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    }
}
```

Seems like a typical case for template specialisation yet C# does not support such feature as far as I know. I was also thinking about static class implementing a strategy pattern to swap the function for grabbing the comparer yet static will be implemented for all types so type-method dictionary lookup is necessary. Generating IL code for this seems to be a last resort and not worth the effort considering the code is not that heavily used.

What is the best way to change the behaviour of a method in question so it will get a special case if T implements IMerge? I ask because theoretically it should be possible to define behaviour at compile time or at least at initialisation time (static constructor) if it won't change during runtime.

Comment: What's the problem with your existing code? While you could cache `typeof(IMerge).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))` in a static `ConditionalWeakDictionary` that's unlikely to be worth the bother and probably wouldn't improve performance that much anyways.

Comment: I added description at the end. It uses reflection to change behaviour which is known at compile time and hence in principle it is not considered a good code.

Comment: Once per type seems a good compromise. The issue is the class itself is not generic, just the method is. I guess this would require creating a separate generic static comparer factory class with a property for grabbing the comparer. Seems tough :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I don't think there is anything wrong with your existing code. Personally I'd keep it as is.

   IMO optimizing this before you have evidence that it's performance critical is premature optimization.
2. If you really want to cache the result of the comparison, you could use something like:

   ```
   static class MergeComparerHelper<T>
   {
       static bool SupportsMerge = typeof(IMerge).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T));
   }
   ```

   This uses the fact that each generic instantiation gets its own static fields. You can use a private nested class for this.

   Note however that this still incurs the cost of a runtime dispatch, since the current implementation of the .NET JITter does not produce specialized implementations for different reference-type `T`s.

Comment: I will leave 1 as it is but 2 looks like a reasonable approach which I will definitely keep bookmarked for a more complicated / needing more optimisation special cases of generic class/method specialisations. It also shows limitations of C# in this area. I'll wait with accepting for a few days just in case. Thanks for help.